# Special chars issue while granting priviliges on mysql database

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, terminal

I came across with an issue while I was trying to grant privileges to a database for a mysql user via t. I think it's because of the special chars in the database name.

This one is working:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -pXz5eaCqwvsT0pAr0gsf0tg1a -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dev_52000_nycny.* TO 'wp_j-5-1-5_nycny'@localhost"
```

That one is not working:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -pXz5eaCqwvsT0pAr0gsf0tg1a -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dev_j-5-1-5_nycny.* TO 'wp_j-5-1-5_nycny'@localhost"
```

I have tried few combinations but no luck:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -pXz5eaCqwvsT0pAr0gsf0tg1a -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'dev_j-5-1-5_nycny'.* TO 'wp_j-5-1-5_nycny'@localhost"

/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -pXz5eaCqwvsT0pAr0gsf0tg1a -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dev_j\-5\-1\-5_nycny.* TO 'wp_j-5-1-5_nycny'@localhost"

/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -pXz5eaCqwvsT0pAr0gsf0tg1a -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'dev_j\-5\-1\-5_nycny'.* TO 'wp_j-5-1-5_nycny'@localhost"
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL uses backticks to quote database, table, and column names that contain special characters. See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

```
/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -pXz5eaCqwvsT0pAr0gsf0tg1a -e 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dev_j-5-1-5_nycny`.* TO "wp_j-5-1-5_nycny"@localhost`
```

Make sure you use single quotes around the `-e` argument, because backticks have special meaning to the shell when they're inside double quoted strings. I also changed the quotes around the username to double quotes to accomodate using single quotes around the whole query.